# zenity list and for loop

Tags: zenity

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do

echo 'bla bla'

echo 'xxx'

echo $i

done | select=$(zenity --list --title="title" --text="text" --column="X" --column="Y" --column="Z");
```

I try to create a checklist with zenity, my problem is that $select is always empty.
I try to do it in few other ways, like this one:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
    x="bla bla"
    y="xxx"
    z="$i"
    table="$table '$x' '$y' '$z'"
done
eval zenity --list --title="title" --text="text" --column="X" --column="Y" --column="Z" $table
```

In this way the $select variable isn't empty but if there are spaces in some variable (like $x for example) zenity split it to 2 (or more) columns.

I need other solution or any fix for my code(s)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this other approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
    echo "bla bla"
    echo "xxx"
    echo "$i"
done | zenity --list --title="title" --text="text" --column="X" --column="Y" --column="Z"
```

Each line populate the table from the first column to the last, and then again on a new row, until the input stream ends.