# dynamic yad lists possible?

Tags: zenity

I wonder if anyone more familiar with `yad` (yet another dialogue) knows if dynamic lists are possible and if so how might one be implemented using the contents of a bash array assigning `FALSE` to each list item?

I have a script that manages multiple LUKS partitions, and so when user selects to mount a partition they are presented with a list of partitions not yet mounted from which to make their next selection. So the upshot is that they cannot select a mount point already mounted.

This is currently managed by presenting the user the list in a terminal, but I would like to try using a `yad` list dialogue if dynamic lists are possible.

From the scant pages detailing `yad` usage online I could not find anything regarding dynamic lists, leading me to believe this is will quite likely not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from zenity example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706029/zenity-list-and-for-loop?rq=1) you could do:

```
devsToMnt=$(for f in "${part_list_array[@]}" ; do echo FALSE ; echo "$f" ; done | yad --list --center --height="400" --checklist --column="Select" --column="Device to mount:" --print-column="2" --multiple --separator=" ")
```

and whatever partitions the user chooses will be available in `$devsToMnt`

Comment: ignore attempted edit. Command works good in subshell in script.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example [on the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/Examples), I would presume that something to the effect of

```
mounts=( "foo" "bar" "baz" )

mp=$(yad --width 300 --entry --title "Mount?" \
    --button="Mount it." \
    --text "Choose mountpoint:" \
    --entry-text \
    "${mounts[@]}")

echo "let's mount $mp"
```

should work.

Comment: Yeah I saw that dynamic drop down lists are possible but they only allow a single selection. So if the user wants to select two or more partitions to mount then I want to allow them to do so as the script does manage mounting / unmounting multiple partitions in succession.

Comment: Does it support checkboxes?  You could dynamically generate a set of those.

Comment: yes checklists are an available option: `yad --list --center --height="400" --checklist --column="Select" --column="Device to mount:" --print-column="2" FALSE selection1 FALSE selection2 TRUE selection3 --multiple --separator=" "` for example. I am creating this command with contents of array but can't seem to run it in a subshell.

Comment: I am trying: `yList="yad --list --center --height=\"400\" --checklist --column=\"Select\" --column=\"Device to mount:\" --print-column=\"2\" --multiple --separator=\" \""` then `for f in "${neMP[@]}" ; do yList=$(echo "$yList"|sed -r "s/^(.*)(--multiple .*)$/\1FALSE ${f} \2/") #; echo "\$yList: yList" ; done` and finally `devsToMnt=( $("$yList") )` to try to run the `yad` command just created, but no luck. Posted loop as oneliner to make posting here easier btw.